# How do I match this pattern in R

Tags: regex, r

I have to match only the first Country name in the pattern below. The country names are given in all upper case letters. I used the following code to get the matches but it matches all the countries.

```
'\\b[A-Z]{2,}.\\b'
```

Eg: In the pattern below, I just want UNITED KINGDOM

```
x = "~ London, Greater London ~ UNITED KINGDOM;~ Ottawa, Ontario ~ CANADA;~,~ AUSTRALIA;~,~ POLAND;~,~ USA"
```

Comment: What code did you use?

Comment: Are all the letters ASCII or are there Unicode ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
regmatches(x, regexpr('\\b[A-Z ]{2,}\\b', x))
# [1] "UNITED KINGDOM"
```

I just added a space to make the character set `[A-Z ]`. Note that `regexpr` gets the first match while `gregexpr` gets all of them (similar to `sub` vs `gsub`).

For more info, I recommend the official docs at `?regexpr`.